# How to sort before skip and limit in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

```
const list = async function({
  end_cursor = 0
} = {}) {
  return await db.collection.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).skip(end_cursor).limit(50);
}
```

Above is the code that I thought it should work, but I found that it doesn't. Here is the evident:

```
  let list1 = await list(0);
  list1 = list1.reduce((o, a)=>{
    let {
      _id
    } = a;
    o[_id] = true;
    return o;
  }, {});

  let list2 = await list(50);
  for (let i of list2) {
    let {
      _id
    } = i;
    if (list1[_id]) {
      console.log('repeated');
      break;
    }
  }
```

If `db.collection.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).skip(end_cursor).limit(50)` works, list1 and list2 should have unique `_id`s, but they don't, instead the console outputs `repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use aggregation for your requirement.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {_id: -1}},
  {$skip: end_cursor}, //value should be a positive integer
  {$limit: 50}
]);
```